# Why does "print" run the command twice?

Tags: python

So I have this code, which returns a series of information about the file. And it returns the output twice, as shown in the second snippet.

```
list = os.listdir(".")
print Style.BRIGHT + "size        info        last-accessed    last-changed     filename" + Style.RESET_ALL
for f in list:
    info = os.stat(f)
    # "  size          info        last-accessed    last-changed     filename
    print " ", info[ST_SIZE], "                                                  " + f
```

And the output:

```
  size        info        last-accessed    last-changed     filename
  6243                                                   .bash_history
  55                                                   .bash_profile
  3                                                   .CFUserTextEncoding
  15364                                                   .DS_Store
  102                                                   .fontconfig
  105                                                   .sh_history
  102                                                   .ssh
  442                                                   .Trash
  0                                                   .Xauthority
  105                                                   console
  6688                                                   console.py
  272                                                   Desktop
  238                                                   Documents
  442                                                   Downloads
  2924                                                   Folder
  1156                                                   Library
  204                                                   Movies
  102                                                   Music
  136                                                   Pictures
  204                                                   Public
  170                                                   Sites
  3914                                                   xetch
size        info        last-accessed    last-changed     filename
  6243                                                   .bash_history
  55                                                   .bash_profile
  3                                                   .CFUserTextEncoding
  15364                                                   .DS_Store
  102                                                   .fontconfig
  105                                                   .sh_history
  102                                                   .ssh
  442                                                   .Trash
  0                                                   .Xauthority
  105                                                   console
  6688                                                   console.py
  272                                                   Desktop
  238                                                   Documents
  442                                                   Downloads
  2924                                                   Folder
  1156                                                   Library
  204                                                   Movies
  102                                                   Music
  136                                                   Pictures
  204                                                   Public
  170                                                   Sites
  3914                                                   xetch
```

Sorry that it's a mesh, but as you would notice, it returned it twice.

Comment: Please format your code readably.

Comment: Since it prints the header twice too, I'm kinda sure that there is something outside your code that is calling it two times; can you show how is this piece of code used?

Comment: You need to learn about how to format strings in Python. That huge string of spaces is *not* the best way of doing it.

Comment: Alright then. And Cynical: the header is printed once, and the code is called with ls()- it's a function.

Comment: No, the headers in your question are printed twice.

Comment: sberry: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: The line "size info last-access..." (aka, header) is printed twice in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you show prints the `size        info...` header exactly once. Since you're seeing it printed twice, this means that *the entire code block is executed twice*.  Why that would be the case is impossible to tell without seeing more code.